# unable to import/use the Nativescript core dark theme

Tags: css, nativescript

i'm trying to import/use the default dark Nativescript theme and getting the following error.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

error:
JS: Error: Css styling failed: Error: undefined:1:10: missing '{'

my app.css:

@import 'nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css';

Comment: Which version of NativeScript?   Which version of the theme?

Comment: @Nathanael i'm using Nativescript v2.4.2 and Nativescript theme-core ^0.1.3

Comment: I would attempt to do a `npm install nativescript-theme-core@latest` and see if that fixes your issue.   0.1.3 is a pretty early version of the theme.

Comment: @Nathanael  I started a new project removed the nativescript-theme-core package and did a npm install nativescript-theme-core@latest  1.0.2 was installed however i'm still getting the same error except now it says undefined1:9 instead of 1:10...  Any idea what else this could be?

Comment: Hmm, I just tested this and it worked for me on Android.
`tns create tnstestcss` then `npm i nativescript-theme-core@latest --save` then `tns platform add android`, then edited the app.css, file and replaced "light" with dark.  Saved, typed `tns run android` and it started with no issues.    Maybe your editor is saving extra garbage to the file or trying to convert it to utf-8 file.

Comment: @Nathanael I had a styleUrls: ['./app.css'] which gave me that error...  I had no idea that the theme was globally accessible...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had styleUrls: ['./app.css'] in my component definition...  Removing that fixed this issue...